# How to get button value to controller?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have view and it has two button which are 'Yes' and 'No'.
If I click 'Yes' redirect one page and if I click 'No' redirect to another page.

This is my view.

```
@using (Html.BeginForm())
 { 
<table  >
 <tr>
    <td >
      Ceremony : 
    </td>
    <td>
       Ceremony at @Model.ceremony_date

    </td>
</tr>

  <tr>
            <td >
              Name :
            </td>
            <td >
               @Model.first_name  @Model.middle_name  @Model.last_name
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
         <td colspan="2" >
            @Html.Partial("_DegreeDetailsByGraduand", @Model.DegreeList)
         </td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
        <td colspan="2" >
        IS information is correct ?
        </tr>
        <tr>
        <td>
         <input type="submit" id="btndegreeconfirmYes" name="btnsearch" class="searchbutton"  value="Yes" />    
         </td>  <td>
          <input type="submit" id="btndegreeconfirmNo" name="btnsearch" class="searchbutton"  value="No" /></td>  
        </tr>
</table>


 }
```

This is my controller

```
[HttpPost]

        public ActionResult CheckData()
        {

            return RedirectToRoute("detailform");
        }
```

I don't know how to get the button value in controller.
How can I do it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Give your submit buttons a name, and then inspect the submitted value in your controller method:

```
<% Html.BeginForm("MyAction", "MyController", FormMethod.Post); %>
<input type="submit" name="submitButton" value="Send" />
<input type="submit" name="submitButton" value="Cancel" />
<% Html.EndForm(); %>



public class MyController : Controller {
    public ActionResult MyAction(string submitButton) {
        switch(submitButton) {
            case "Send":
                // delegate sending to another controller action

            case "Cancel":
                // call another action to perform the cancellation

            default:
                // If they've submitted the form without a submitButton, 
                // just return the view again.
                return(View());
        }
    }
```

}

Hope this helps:

Answer (score 3):

I supposed you are using MVC + razor engine.

Do like this:

your 2 buttons:

```
<input type="submit" value="Yes" id="buttonYes"/>
<input type="submit" value="Cancel" id="buttonCancel"/>
```

your form:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Method", "Controller", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data", id = "CreateReportForm" }))
{ 
…
}
```

add this javascript to your form. Adapt your action to the action on the controller that will redirect:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#buttonYes").click(function () {
            $('form#CreateReportForm').attr({ action: "Controller/Create" });
        });
        $("#buttonCancel").click(function () {
            $('form#CreateReportForm').attr({ action: " Controller /Cancel" });
        });
    });

</script>
```

Comment: You don't really need to use javascript for this.

Answer (score 2):

Try like this:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult CheckData(string btnSearch)
{
    if (btnSearch == "Yes") {
        // The Yes submit button was clicked
    } else if (btnSearch == "No") {
        // The No submit button was clicked
    }
    return RedirectToRoute("detailform");
}
```

But it is usually better not to test against the text of the button but against a predefined value because the text could change and your controller action might break:

```
<button type="submit" name="btnsearch" value="yes">Yeah</button>
<button type="submit" name="btnsearch" value="no">Nope, I don't want to do this</button>
```

and then:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult CheckData(string btnSearch)
{
    if (btnSearch == "yes") {
        // The Yes submit button was clicked
    } else if (btnSearch == "no") {
        // The No submit button was clicked
    }
    return RedirectToRoute("detailform");
}
```

And there's even a better approach where you could dispatch to a different controller action based on which button was clicked. Check [`this article`](http://blog.ashmind.com/2010/03/15/multiple-submit-buttons-with-asp-net-mvc-final-solution/) out.

You could have a form whose action equals to `Action`:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Action", "Post")) 
{
  <input type="submit" name="saveDraft" value="Save Draft" />
  <input type="submit" name="publish" value="Publish" />
}
```

and then have 2 controller actions in the corresponding controller:

```
public class PostController : Controller 
{
    [HttpParamAction]
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult SaveDraft(...) 
    {
        // ...
    }

    [HttpParamAction]
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Publish(...) 
    {
        // ...
    }
}
```

and here's the definition of the custom action name selector:

```
public class HttpParamActionAttribute : ActionNameSelectorAttribute 
{
    public override bool IsValidName(ControllerContext controllerContext, string actionName, MethodInfo methodInfo) 
    {
        if (actionName.Equals(methodInfo.Name, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
        {
            return true;
        }

        if (!actionName.Equals("Action", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
        {
            return false;
        }

        var request = controllerContext.RequestContext.HttpContext.Request;
        return request[methodInfo.Name] != null;
    }
}
```

Now depending on which submit button is clicked the proper controller action will be invoked.

Comment: Its worth noting that if you want to go with a single controller action to handle this, but want less magic strings, a view based enum which is used as the value for the controller to interpret worked as a nice modification for me!

Answer (score 1):

use FormValueRequired attribute like this:

```
[HttpPost]
[FormValueRequired("btndegreeconfirmYes")]        
     public ActionResult CheckData()
     {
       Response.Write(submit);                    
       return RedirectToRoute("detailform");
     }
```

and you need to change your markup as follow:

EDIT: use two nested form

```
    @using (Html.BeginForm())
    {
      @using (Html.BeginForm())
       {
           .
           .
           .       
      <input type="submit" id="btndegreeconfirmYes" name="btndegreeconfirmYes"class="searchbutton" value="Yes" />           
       }
<input type="submit" id="btndegreeconfirmNo" name="btndegreeconfirmNo"    class="searchbutton"  value="No" /></td>
    }
```

by doing this submitting form with first submit button will send only its own value and then you can use it in FromValueRquired attribute.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a handler so your controller can route your post according to the submit element name.

http://stevenbey.com/enable-multiple-submit-buttons-in-aspnet-mvc

For example, a controller can handle a submit element with the name "Action_Publish" like this:

```
[HttpPost, FormAction(Prefix = "Action_")]    
public ActionResult Publish()    
{        
//...  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Normally I use the accepted answer, but it doesn't appear to work when you are already passing a model. And adding it as a property to the model doesn't seem to work either.

Here's another simple solution for when you are passing a model:

- Add a SubmitButton property to your model
- Add a hidden input with a name and id of SubmitButton
- In your submit inputs, use onclick to set the hidden input value

  ```
  <input type="hidden" id="SubmitButton" name="SubmitButton" value="save" />

  <input type="submit" value="Clear" onclick="$('#SubmitButton').val('clear');" />
  <input type="submit" value="Save" />
  ```